# Change date string format of txt file on OSX

Tags: awk, sed

I am trying to change the date format of text within a file. eg from D24/09/15 to D09/24/15. I have tried multiple SED and AWK methods without success, i think because i am on OSX. Can anyone pls offer a suggestion?

many thanks

a sample extract is as follows:

```
^
D24/09/15
T-99.90
PTEXT AND MORETXT  9146410
^
^
D16/05/15
T-89.90
PTEXT AND MORETXT  9146411
^
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try

```
sed -E 's_D([0-9]+)/([0-9]+)/_D\2/\1/_g' file
```

or in OSx

```
sed 's_D\([0-9]*[0-9]\)/\([0-9]*[0-9]\)/_D\2/\1/_g' file
```

you get,

```
^
D09/24/15
T-99.90
PTEXT AND MORETXT  9146410
^
^
D05/16/15
T-89.90
PTEXT AND MORETXT  9146411
^
```